# Review star rating in Google search results: "The review has no reviewed item specified"

Tags: blogger, google-rich-snippets

I have a problem in my Structured Data Testing Tool it says "The review has no reviewed item specified."

```
<!-- Review Star Rating In Google Search Results -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <div>
        <div itemscope itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Review'>
            <div style='display:none;'>
                Item Reviewed: <span itemprop='itemreviewed'><data:post.title/></span>
                Description: <span itemprop='description'><data:blog.metaDescription/></span>
                Rating: <span itemprop='rating'>5</span>
                Reviewed By: <span itemprop='reviewer'><data:post.author/></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</b:if>
<!-- Review Star Rating In Google Search Results -->
```

I just aiming for my blogger post to have star rating at Google search result.

Comment: Why don’t you use Schema.org? Data-Vocabulary.org is no longer maintained.

Comment: I just found it in some blog. I think that code is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

[itemReviewed](https://schema.org/itemReviewed) should be a [Thing](https://schema.org/Thing), not just text, according to schema.org. Google has further conditions, namely that [itemReviewed for a Review](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews) should be a [LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness), [Movie](https://schema.org/Movie) or [Book](https://schema.org/Book).

Comment: OP is using Data-Vocabulary.org (`http://data-vocabulary.org/Review`) in the example, not Schema.org.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div style='display:none;'>
<div class='vcard' id='hcard-templatoid'>
<span itemprop='description'><span itemprop='itemreviewed'><data:post.title/></span></span>
<time itemprop='dtreviewed'><data:post.timestampISO8601/></time>
Rating: <span itemprop='rating'>5</span>
Posted by: <span class='fn n'>
<span class='given-name' itemprop='reviewer'><data:post.author/></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</b:if>
```

Source: [How To Show Star Ratings In Google Search Results - Blogger](https://101helper.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-show-star-ratings-in-google-blogger.html)